Jenkins Pipeline Fails to Execute SonarQube Scanner: not found Error
I'm running a Jenkins pipeline to perform a SonarQube analysis on my project, but the build fails during the SonarQube scanning stage. I'm using the SonarQube plugin in Jenkins, and below is the error log.
The pipeline fails with the following error: "ERROR: Not authorized. Please check the user token in the property 'sonar.token' or the credentials in the properties 'sonar.login' and 'sonar.password'." I suspect there's an issue with the authentication token or credentials used for SonarQube.

/root/jenkins-slave/tools/hudson.plugins.sonar.SonarRunnerInstallation/sonar/bin/sonar-scanner -Dsonar.projectKey=AHN-frontend-next.js-cms -Dsonar.sources=. -Dsonar.host.url=https://sonarqube.techdigitem.com/ -Dsonar.login=squ_daf0821b5f40d18f1442e78918daba8eb645f7d9
ERROR: Not authorized. Please check the user token in the property 'sonar.token'

I've verified that the token is correct and has the necessary permissions in SonarQube. I also checked the Jenkins configuration for the SonarQube plugin, and it points to the correct SonarQube server URL.
Could anyone help me understand why the authentication might be failing or suggest what else I can check to resolve this issue?


"Assuming SonarQube is configured in Jenkins" - are you sure it's a correct assumption? SonarQube plugin doesn't automatically provide any binaries, it just sets the corresponding environment variables and injects the results provided by the SonarQube server into Jenkins build results.


yes i have added the jenkins webhook in sonarqube and from there i have generated a user token and added into my jenkins credentials as secret text and i have also added the sonar server in my jenkins tools and system config

i also have one more sonarqube server and when i tested it on new jenkins slave it worked fine but i dont know why it is not working on my secound sonarqube server i also tried to comapre the logs they genrated while running the pipeline i done some changes in my job basically i copy pasted the jenkins pipeline code from running sonarqube pipeline and i got log saying
Not authorized. Please check the user token in the property 'sonar.token' or the credentials in the properties 'sonar.login' and 'sonar.password'.

Still, you didn't mention the scanner binaries, did you install them to your agents?

no i didnt installed any sonar binary in to my jenkins slave

INFO: Scanner configuration file: /root/jenkins-slave/tools/hudson.plugins.sonar.SonarRunnerInstallation/sonar/conf/sonar-scanner.properties
INFO: Project root configuration file: NONE
INFO: SonarScanner 5.0.1.3006
INFO: Java 17.0.10 Eclipse Adoptium (64-bit)
INFO: Linux 5.4.0-176-generic amd64
INFO: User cache: /root/.sonar/cache
INFO: Analyzing on SonarQube server 10.4.1.88267
INFO: Default locale: "en", source code encoding: "UTF-8" (analysis is platform dependent)
INFO: Load global settings
INFO: -------------------------------------------
INFO: EXECUTION FAILURE

Please don't use the comments for logs. Instead, [edit] your question. Regarding the binaries - this seems to be the reason. You should either install them or use the corresponding plugin for your build tool.

i have edited my query please let me know it is helpful or not and what i can do to reslove this issue

Thanks Alexander pletnev  i have got the solution of my problem i used another method to install to install SonarQube. i just reinstalled my SonarQube from the beginning using this command " docker run -itd --name sonarqube-server -p 9000:9000 sonarqube:lts-community " previously i was usnig the documentation
https://medium.com/@chiemelaumeh1/how-to-install-sonarqube-using-docker-compose-on-ubuntu-linux-perform-code-analysis-using-98dfe2eb7044
it didn't helped me at all even it made it worse
